mat-autocomplete optionSelected does not get triggered by mouse event
I am using mat-autocomplete and input form control inside a custom cell editor for ag grid in angular.
mat-autocomplete only reacts to keyboard event but not mouse event. Does anyone know how to fix this?
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="control"/>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

I've tried optionSelected in mat-autocomplete, onSelectionChange in mat-option, click in mat-option
